# Passing an array to function without explicit array size

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and I have 2 questions on passing arrays to a function (which may be the same thing).

1. When passing an array to a function by reference, doesn't parameter require explicit size information as in `void my_func (const T &array)` instead of `void my_func (const T (&array)[10])`?
2. What is the difference between a function having an array pointer parameter `void my_func (const T* array)` and `void my_func (const T(* array)[10])`(with or without explicit array size)?

Below is the code which accepts any size of array without explicitly passing array size:

```
template<typename _Ret, //return type
         typename _Coll> //collection type, no size argument
_Ret Sum(const _Coll& c) {

        _Ret sum = 0;
        for (auto& v : c)
                sum += v;
        return sum;
}

int main() {
        // With regular array, Passed as reference
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        std::cout << Sum<int64_t>(arr) << "\n"; //15

        // With vector 
        std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        std::cout << Sum<int64_t>(vec) << "\n"; //15
        return 0;
}
```

The article from which this example originates says as below:

> Additionally, the use of templates can even avoid the unsightly array reference syntax and make the code work for any array size.

If this works, then is the general template for any array size as below unnecessary?

```
template<typename T, std::size_t S>
void my_func(T (&arr)[S]) {
        ... ...;
}
```

And also a side question, why does`template<typename _Ret, typename _Coll>` requires 2 template arguments but `Sum<int64_t>(arr)` specifies only 1 template argument?

Comment: Generally, C-arrays aren't passed by reference, since the pass-by-value pointer and size get the job done just fine. There's likely a compatibility reason in there as well. It's not necessary to ever state the size of the 1st dimension of a C-array. Hopefully, `std::span` makes all of this go away. It's a cool function, though.

Comment: The fact you've named an argument `array` doesn't force the compiler to only accept array arguments and reject everything else.  `const T &array` (where `T` is a template parameter) can match a literal of type `int` - which is undesirable if the function cannot do anything meaningful if the argument is not a collection.  Whereas `const T (&array)[10]` means the compiler will reject any argument that is not an array of `10` elements,  while `const T (&array)[S]` (where `S` is a templated argument with integral type) is acceptable for an array of any size.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. when passing an array to a function by reference, does parameter not require explicit size information as in void my_func (const T &array) instead of void my_func (const T (&array)[10])?

A reference parameter does not necessarily have to be reference to an array.

`const T &` is a reference to a `const T`. If `T` type alias of `int[10]` for example, then `const T &` is `const int (&)[10]` i.e. reference to an array of 10 `const int`. If `T` is a template type parameter, then the template can be instantiated with different types, including array types of different sizes and also including non-array types.

`const T (&)[10]` is a reference to an array of 10 `const T`.

You don't need to pass size information separately when the size information is encoded in the type of the parameter, such as is the case when the parameter is a reference to an array.

> But the example in my question neither defines alias

You're mistaken. Your example is a template function and a template type parameter *is* a type alias.

> Function calling statement simply passes arr which is converted(decayed) into a pointer to int.

You're mistaken. `arr` does not decay to pointer to int when the reference is bound to it. Array decaying happens upon an lvalue to rvalue conversion. There is no such conversion when binding a reference to an object.

---

> 2. what is the difference between a function having an array pointer paremeter void my_func (const T* array) and void my_func (const T(* array)[10])(with or without explicit array size) *new version*?

`const T*` is a pointer to `const T`.

`const T(*)[10]` is pointer to `const T[10]` i.e. pointer to an array of 10 `T`. For example, if `T` is an alias of `int`, then former is `const int*` and latter is `const int(*)[10]`.

Note that if `T` is an array, then the former can also be a pointer to an array. For example if `T` is `int[42]`, then former is `const int(*)[42]` i.e. a pointer to an array of 42 `const int` while the latter is `const int(*)[42][10]` i.e. pointer to an array of 10 arrays of 42 `const int`.

> ... and void my_func (const T* array[10])(with or without explicit array size) *old version*?

`const T* array[10]` is an array of 10 pointers to `const T`. However, a function parameter is never an array in C++. If a function is declared with an array parameter, that parameter is adjusted to be  a pointer to element of such array. The element of an array of 10 pointers to `const T` is a pointer to `const T` i.e. `const T*` and a pointer to such object is `const T**`. As such, this parameter is actually `const T**`.

The difference between `const T*` and `const T**` is that latter is a pointer to the former.

> If this works, then is the general template for any array size as below unnecessary?

It depends. If you don't need it, then it is unnecessary for your use case.

But that doesn't mean that it would be unnecessary altogether. For example, if you need a function overload that accepts **only** arrays, then you cannot use a `T&` parameter which can accept arguments that are not arrays.

> why does `template<typename _Ret, typename _Coll>` requires 2 template arguments

Because the `S` in `T (&arr)[S]` has to be a template value parameter in order for the reference to be bound to arrays of any size. If you used a non-variable constant such as `T (&arr)[10]`, then you could only accept arrays of one size.

> but `Sum<int64_t>(arr)` specifies only 1 template argument?

This one doesn't use a reference to an array of `S` elements, so there is no need for a template value parameter `S`.

---

`_Ret` and `_Coll` names are reserved to the language implementation. By defining those names as template parameters, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. Do not define reserved names. You should choose other names for the template parameters.

Comment: yes, for the 2nd question, I edited my mistake. So `const T* array[10]` is now `const T(* array)[10]`, which is a pointer to an array, which was my intention.

Comment: For your answer to my 1st question, I understand that alias of int [10] will conveniently do the job. But the example in my question neither defines alias nor passes array size. Function calling statement simply passes _arr_ which is converted(decayed) into a _pointer to int_.

Comment: @Sean In short: Yes, you do have a type alias and no, the array does not decay. See my edited answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming `T` is not an array, `void my_func (const T &array)` would not be the right way of trying that, since that expects a reference to an `T`, not an array. The right way of testing this would probably be `void my_func(const T (&array)[])`:

```
#include <iostream>

void my_func(const int (&)[]) {}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b[] = {1, 2, 3};
    my_func(b);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try running this, I get an error: `error: parameter ‘<anonymous>’ includes reference to array of unknown bound ‘const int []’`. Replacing `const int (&)[]` with `const int (&)[3]` makes it work. So no, you have to specify the size of the array.

---

2. Those are two completely different things. `void my_func(const T *array)` is equivalent to `void my_func(const T array[])` while `void my_func(const T (*array)[10])` is equivalent to `void my_func(const T array[][10])`.

---

[C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io/) is a very nice place to see how templates expand. When we do `Sum<int64_t>(arr)`, a new function of `Sum` is created from the template that is `int64_t Sum<int64_t, int [5]>(int const (&c)[5])`. As you can see, you don't have to specify the size now because the template will do it for you. Every time you pass a different size array to `Sum`, a new function will be created to work with that size.

> and also a side question, `template<typename _Ret, typename _Coll>` requires 2 template arguments but why `does Sum<int64_t>(arr)` specifies only 1 template argument?

Because the second argument is deduced. Since the compiler knows that you're passing an `int [5]` to the function, you don't need to pass the type. However, there is no way for it to know the return type, so you have to pass the type of that.

Comment: yes, for the 2nd question, I edited my mistake. So `const T* array[10]` is now `const T(* array)[10]`, which is a pointer to an array.